# Modx запрос where

Tags: modx

Есть следующий запрос через `pdoresource`, но `where` перетирает значение `parents`:

```php
$data["sort_false"] = $modx->runSnippet('pdoResources', [
    'select' => 'id, condition, maxday, maxsum, minday, minsum, pagetitle',
    'parents' => 2,
    'depth' => 1,
    'limit' => null,
    'sortdir' => 'ASC',
    'includeTVs' => 'condition, minsum, maxsum, minday, maxday',
    'where' => ["minsum>$money OR $money>maxsum OR minday>$day OR $day>maxday"],
    'tvPrefix' => '',
    'return' => 'json'
]);
```

Как в `where` прописать значение `parents`, подскажите, кто знает.

Answer (score 0):

насколько я помню `parent` говорит, что искать записи в ресурсе с id родителя 2, и внутри него идет поиск по детям, и если вы не ограничиваете выборку данных `limit` не нужно упоминать в принципе (`limit => null` - убрать), попробуйте пересмотреть опцию where, так как непонятно, что именно хотите вытащить, если вы пытаетесь найти в диапазоне  используйте `beetween` в запросе